# Where Clause Index Scan - Index Seek

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below table:

```
CREATE TABLE Test
(
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    col1 varchar(37) NULL,
    testDate datetime NULL 
)

insert Test

select null
go 700000 

select cast(NEWID() as varchar(37))
go 300000
```

And below indexes:

```
create clustered index CIX on Test(ID)
create nonclustered index IX_RegularIndex on Test(col1)
create nonclustered index IX_RegularDateIndex on Test(testDate)
```

When I query on my table:

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON
select * from Test  where col1=NEWID()
select * from Test  where TestDate=GETDATE()
```

First is making index scan whereas the second index seek. I expect that both of them must make index seek. Why does the first make index scan?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an implicit convert generated becuase the [**`NEWID()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx) function returns a value which is of `uniqueidentifier` datatype, and that is different than your `VARCHAR` datatype declared for the column.

Just try hovering your mouse over the `SELECT` part of the plan, where there is a "warning" sign.

Due to the fact that there is a mismatch between compared datatypes, the optimizer can't look at statistics and estimate how many rows with that `NEWID()` value there are in the table.

And because of the implicit convert, the optimizer thus decides that it is better to go and get all the rows (thus the `SCAN`), then pass them through the `FILTER` operation, where it does a conversion of the value of `Col1` to a `uniqueidentifier` datatype and then removing the additional rows that do not match the filter condition.

As opposed to `GETDATE()` which returns a `datetime` value, which is of the same datatype as your `testDate` column, so no datatype conversion is needed and values can be compared as they are.

Comment: More information about implicit conversions that will cause an Index Scan can be found here: https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/implicit-conversions-that-cause-index-scans/

Comment: Yes, there is so much information out there about implicit converts, I will try to add some as well. But most of the times this is one of the culprits.